# ImportError: No module named 'urllib3' in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

I have a Jupyter notebook (in Google Cloud Datalab) with a `python3` kernel. In that notebook

```
import urllib3
```

produces `ImportError: No module named 'urllib3'`, but

```
%%bash
pip list | grep urllib3
```

produces `urllib3 (1.22)`. What is going on here? Why can I not import from `urllib3` in this notebook?

Comment: try pip3 to see all python3 packages

Comment: @kessi Excellent. `pip3 install urllib3` resolves the issue. If you want to turn your comment into an answer I shall accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pip3 to see all python3 packages